# foreach loop returns multiple copies of the same entry

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

Im trying to list each 'name' entry from a json file. However I keep getting the same entry copied a few times for each parent. For example 'Name' returns DennisDennisDennisDennis. I cant remove the [3] (or any number that is inside it) because then my page will turn up blank. How to I code it that next time it lists each of the names in the json? This is my code:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=>"X-AUTH-TOKEN: 41e509ad68f0......"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts); 

$url    = 'workingurlhere'; 
$data   = file_get_contents($url, true, $context); 
$result = json_decode($data); 

foreach ($result as $all){
    echo $result -> data[3] -> Name;   
}


?>
```

Comment: You keep echoing the same thing. No wonder it's showing you the same thing.

Comment: `foreach ( array as element ) echo element->property`

Comment: var_dump your $result, and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reference $all not $result.

```
foreach ($result as $all){
  echo $all -> data[3] -> Name;   
}
```

Comment: That gives me a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the structure of the json, this is a half guess and half instinct.

```
foreach ($result as $all){
    echo $all -> data[3] -> Name;   
}
```

Or, if you need to loop on `data` itself:

```
foreach ($result->data as $entry){
    echo $entry -> Name;   
}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd say probably there is a high chance that it could be `foreach ($result->data as $data) echo $data->Name;` as well

Comment: That could be it.. But we need a dump to know for sure.

Comment: @sidyll thats it! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're always referencing the original array `$result`. So you'll always get the same result.

```
foreach ($result as $all){
    echo $result->data[3]->Name; // Always printing the same index.   
}
```

I would estimate a guess the following might work, but without seeing what data is in `$result` I can't be 100% certain.

```
foreach ($result->data as $values){
    echo $values->Name;   
}
```

If that doesn't work it may be worth editing your original question with what `$result` contains.